# Upload a File from Local Angular Folder to Server

Tags: javascript, html, angular, file-upload, stream

I Have placed four static files in Assets/Image Folder in my Angular 8 app.
User has provision to select one File.

My problem is that, I want to upload the selected file to the server in his own Server Folder.

I tried this

```
var File = new file( new File(["img1"],"./assets/images/nathure_image1.png");
```

and send this file to server

```
 public uploadImage(fileToUpload: File): Observable<any> {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fileKey', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    return this.http.post(this.appSettings.API_Config + this.controllerName + '/uploadImage', formData);
}
```

but it is wrong it create new file and not sends already existing File

Please let me know if my question is unclear ,
I can help with more details

I just want to send my existing client file to serve through API

Thanks for any help

Comment: You need to pick the image using HTMLInput OR Load image and extract base64 and encode it as an image in server.

Comment: How to load that image,, Can you please explain